# Drawing database tables in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

I am bit confused about how can i draw a table like this using tikz. Any ideas please?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing what you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have. See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a typical "how do I draw this graphic" question. Although asked to elaborate more and/or show his own attempts there was nor reaction within three days.

Comment: @BenediktBauer and to any other close voters: I sort of agree, but if this one is closed, then over half of the `tikz` questions should also go

Answer (score 28):

This answer uses

- the `ext.positioning-plus` library (for `west below=of`),
- the `ext.node-families` library
  (for `node family/text width [align]`),
- and the `ext.paths-ortho` library
  (for `|-|` = `vertical horizontal vertical`)
  from my [`tikz-ext`ensions package](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-ext),
- the `matrix` library,
- a redefinition of the `left delimiter` key from the `matrix`
  library (`left delimiter=\{` will still work) and
- a few keys/styles.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,         % current library for arrows
  matrix,              % for delimiters and matrix of nodes
  ext.node-families,   % for node family/text width
  ext.positioning-plus,% for west below=of
  ext.paths.ortho      % for vertical horizontal vertical (|-|)
}
\tikzset{% always useful
  rows/.style 2 args={
    /utils/temp/.style={row ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}},
  columns/.style 2 args={
    /utils/temp/.style={column ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}}},
    /utils/temp/.list={#1}}}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  left delimiter/.style 2 args={append after command={% overwriting original
    \tikz@delimiter{south east}{south west}% second argument is optional
    {every delimiter,every left delimiter,#2}{south}{north}{#1}{.}{\pgf@y}}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Latex, node distance=2cm,
  my matrix/.style={
    draw, matrix of nodes,
    left delimiter=\{{label={[anchor=south,rotate=90]left:Relation}},
    nodes={
      node family/text width/.expanded=%
        \tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn,
      node family/text width align=left,
      inner xsep=+.5\tabcolsep, inner ysep=+0pt, align=left},
    inner sep=.5\pgflinewidth,
    font=\strut\ttfamily,
    rows={1}{fill=red!20},
  }
]
\matrix[my matrix] (m1) {
  branchNo & street        & city     & postcode \\
  B005     &  22 Deer   Rd & London   & SW1 4EH \\
  B007     &  16 Argyll St & Aberdeen & AB2 3SU \\
  B003     & 163 Main   St & Glasgow  & G11 9QZ \\
  B004     &  32 Manse  Rd & Bristol  & BS99 1NZ \\
  B002     &  56 Clover Dr & Lond     & NW10 6EU \\
};
\matrix[
  my matrix,
  west below=of m1,
  columns={6,...,8}{node family/text width align=right},
  columns={5}{node family/text width align=center}
] (m2) {
  staffNo & fName & IName & position   & sex & DOB       & salary & branchNo \\
  SL21    & John  & White & Manager    & M   & 1-Oct-45  & 30000  & B005     \\
  SG37    & Ann   & Beech & Assistant  & F   & 10-Nov-60 & 12000  & B003     \\
  SG14    & David & Ford  & Supervisor & M   & 24-Mar-58 & 18000  & B003     \\
  SA9     & Mary  & Howe  & Assistant  & F   & 19-Feb-70 &  9000  & B007     \\
  SG5     & Susan & Brand & Manager    & F   & 3-Jun-40  & 24000  & B003     \\
  SL41    & Julie & Lee   & Assistant  & F   & 13-Jun-65 &  9000  & B005     \\
};

\path[->] node[above=+1cm of m1] (attrib) {Attributes}
  \foreach \col in {1,...,4} {edge (m1-1-\col)};
\path[node distance=.25em, font=\bfseries] node[west above=of m1] {Branch}
                                           node[west above=of m2] {Staff};

\path[<->] (m1-6-1) edge[vertical horizontal vertical, ortho/ratio=.65, above]
  node[pos=.3333] {Primary key} node[pos=.6667] {Foreign key} (m2-1-8)
  ([yshift=-.25cm] m1.south west) edge node[below] {Degree}
                                             ([yshift=-.25cm] m1.south east)
  ([xshift=.25cm] m1-1-4.south east) edge node[rotate=90,below] {Cardinality}
                                             ([xshift=.25cm]  m1.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: It looks like the attributes are not visible for me. The culprit is "rows={1}{fill=myRed}}". How to repair it? And do you have any minimal working example with just one table?

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk, The original answer was posted at 2013, now it's 2022, something might changed, :). Just append `, text=black` after `rows={1}{fill=myRed}`, and you can see the words. That's due to the word's color is the same as the filling color.

Comment: Thanks! After 2 years I can finally use it !

Comment: @BartoszBednarczyk I couldn't reproduce your problem. Anyway, I've updated the answer so that it uses the updated libraries that are now on CTAN (and should be available to download as a normal package).

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Does your code still work today on your computer? Because on mine the compilation fails. Thx

Comment: @VincentISOZ You're right. I've changed something small. `hvvh/ratio=.65` in the last path should be either `ortho/ratio=.65` (preferred) or `hvvh={ratio=.65}` (or `ortho={ratio=.65}`). My goal was to move away from the namespaces `/tikz/hvvh` and `/tikz/udlr` to a common `/tikz/ortho` but it's more complex …