# Drawing SQL tables

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I'd like to draw SQL tables, some example content and relations between the id's. Output should be something like below, without the contents.

[image: Relational model]

Could you help me with a head start here? Is there any libraries for this already?

Comment: I would suggest to use `UML`, as it is the correct way of relational database presentation tool. If you wanna go that way, then you can have a look at [**TikZ-UML**](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en).

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134821/drawing-database-tables-in-tikz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An example with some `matrix` nodes. Fixing nodes width is necessary to correctly draw empty cells borders.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
table/.style={matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells, column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth, nodes={draw,anchor=center,minimum width=2cm,minimum height=2cm}, row 1/.style={nodes={minimum height=1cm}}}]

\matrix(Dept) [table, label=above:Department] {
    No & Name \\ & \\};

\matrix(Professor) [table, label=above:Professor, right=1cm of Dept] {
    No & Name & DeptNo & Courses \\ & & & \\};

\matrix(Course) [table, label=above:Course, below=1.25cm of Dept] {
    No & DeptNo & Prof ID & Unit \\ & & & \\};

\matrix(Student) [table, label=above:Course, right=1cm of Course] {
    ID & Name & Course \\ & & \\};

\draw (Dept-2-1.south)--++(0,-.5)-|(Professor-2-3);
\draw (Professor-2-4.south)--++(0,-.75)-|(Course-1-1.north);
\draw (Course-2-1.south)--++(0,-.5)-|(Student-2-3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Very useful answer. However, I do have problems with migrating this into article document class. \usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning} isn't working in article.

Comment: @t-my you need to include `\usepackage{tikz}` before usetikzlabry. The example didn't use it because standalone class automatically loads it with tikz option.