# Tikz fill color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, matrices, loops, preamble

At the moment I'm using this command in the preamble to fill the color of the specified row with grey:

```
 row 2/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!10}
        }
```

Unfortunately I have to write this for every line.
Can't I say something like

```
 row 1-10/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!10}
        }
```

Copy from answer:

Thanks for your answers. Though I'm not sure what's not clear in my example the problem is that I wanted to use the row option (within `\tikzset{}` before `\begin{document}` ) because (maybe I don't know how else to do it) I only want certain rows to be colored that way not everything. Other rows have a different color such that everything looks nice and colorful as it should be. Since I'm very new to `tikz` I solved this in an awkward way by writing

```
\tixset{
  row 2/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!10}
        },
                        row 3/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!10}
        },
                        row 4/.style={
            nodes={fill=gray!10}
        },
        column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=14em}
        },
                        column 3/.style={
            nodes={text width=9em}
        },
                            column 4/.style={
            nodes={text width=9em}
        }
}
```

Here I also specified different widths for the columns. Probably as well this one can solve better by not writing the entire `./style` every time...
@last: `myrowstyle` is just a name or? so my new definition to later call it am I right?

## MWE [copied from deleted answer by cfr]

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        minimum height=1.5em,
        text depth=0.5em,
        text height=1em,
                text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
%%
                                row 1/.style={
            nodes={
                fill=black,
                text=white,
                %font=\bfseries
            }
        },
                myrowstyle/.style={
                    row #1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
        },
             column 1/.style={
            nodes={text width=14em}
        },
                        column 3/.style={
            nodes={text width=9em}
        },
                            column 4/.style={
            nodes={text width=9em}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (first) [table,text width=4em, myrowstyle/.list={1,2,3}, row 2/.style={text depth=1.5em}, ampersand replacement=\&]
{ 
        ... \& \# ...\& \# ... \& ... \\
     01.06.-02.06. \break (hello world) \& 1 \& 2 \& \\
     02.06.-03.06. (hello) \& 3 \& 3 \& \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking.  Other users will be able to answer your question better if you provide (a) more context and (b) a minimal working example that begins with `\documentclass{...}` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Why use the `row` styles at all, can't you just add `nodes={fill=gray!10}` to the `matrix` options directly?

Comment: See the `rows` and `columns` keys in [my answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137581). You can use `rows={1,3,8,...,12}{fill=gray!10}` or—taken from the linked answer—`columns={6,...,8}{align=right}, columns={5}{align=center}`

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `/.list` handler.

```
\tikzset{myrowstyle/.style = {row #1/.style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}}
```

and later in the picture you can then use

```
myrowstyle/.list={1,...,10}
```

or any other argument list.

Answer (score 3):

This answer demonstrates how to modify your MWE to use the suggestions provided in comments and other answers.

The reason that  [Qrrbrbirlbel's suggestion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312594/tikz-fill-color#comment760760_312594) seemed not to work is probably that you didn't include the code to which the comment directed you. It is difficult to say for sure because your reported failure concerned a code fragment and not a complete example, which always makes it difficult to diagnose (let alone solve) problems.

Basically, you need to actually *include* the relevant part of Qrrbrbirlbel's code if it is to do you any good. You can't expect TikZ to find it by looking up [Qrrbrbirlbel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137581/)!

```
\tikzset{
  rows/.style 2 args={%
    /utils/temp/.style={%
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}},
    },
    /utils/temp/.list={#1},
  },
  columns/.style 2 args={%
    /utils/temp/.style={%
      column ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}},
    },
    /utils/temp/.list={#1},
  },
}
```

The reason that [percusse's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312595/) appears not to work is that your question provided insufficient information about the context in which you wanted to use the code. As a result, it is necessary to modify the suggested `.style` definition to take account of the context in which you wish to use the `.list` by doubling the hashes in the usual way to ensure they refer to the correct argument.

```
    my row style/.style={
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
    },
```

This can also be modified to deal with a list of `{<row>}{<colour>}` pairs, if desired.

```
    my other row style/.style n args=2{
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={fill=##2}}
    },
```

This is why it is so important to provide a complete minimal working example when you ask a question.

The following modification of your MWE demonstrates all 3 of the above approaches.

```
\documentclass[table]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{% from Qrrbrbirlbel's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137581/
  rows/.style 2 args={%
    /utils/temp/.style={%
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}},
    },
    /utils/temp/.list={#1},
  },
  columns/.style 2 args={%
    /utils/temp/.style={%
      column ##1/.append style={nodes={#2}},
    },
    /utils/temp/.list={#1},
  },
}
\tikzset{
  table/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes={
      rectangle,
      draw=black,
      align=center,
    },
    minimum height=1.5em,
    text depth=0.5em,
    text height=1em,
    text centered,
    nodes in empty cells,
    row 1/.style={
      nodes={
        fill=black,
        text=white,
      }
    },
    my row style/.style={% from percusse's answer at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/312595/ but we need to double the hashes in this case in order to use it as the OP wants below
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={fill=gray!10}}
    },
    my other row style/.style n args=2{
      row ##1/.append style={nodes={fill=##2}}
    },
    column 1/.append style={
      nodes={text width=8em}
    },
    column 3/.append style={
      nodes={text width=5em}
    },
    column 4/.append style={
      nodes={text width=5em}
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (first) [table, ampersand replacement=\&, text width=4em, my row style/.list={2}, my other row style/.list={{3}{cyan}}, rows={2,3}{text depth=1.5em}, ]
    {
      ... \& \# ...\& \# ... \& ... \\
      01.06.-02.06. \break (hello world) \& 1 \& 2 \& \\
      02.06.-03.06. (hello) \& 3 \& 3 \& \\
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured rows]