# Nesting pgfmatrix for the Nested Relational Model

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to use the pgfmatrix representation for relational tables as provided in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134821/drawing-database-tables-in-tikz) former example but, this approach suffers from the following error:

> Package pgf Error: You cannot nest pgfmatrix environments, yet. 001 &
>   \matrix at (10,0) (m2) {

This feature for me is required because I want to represent the nested relational model, and hence it should be possible to define something as in this MWE (**EDIT**) while keeping the primary key and foreign keys arrows as in the aformentioned example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m1) {
    id & table \\
    001     &   \matrix at (10,0) (m2) {
        id & date \\
        100    & 30-Dic-2016 \\
    };     \\
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there an alternative way to produce the same representation or, even better, is there a way to trick tikz to effectively nest the two parts? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** 
Desired effect without TiKz: [image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\usepackage[osf,sc]{mathpazo}
\usepackage{inconsolata}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{
  | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
  | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
  | >{\sffamily\raggedright}c
  | >{\sffamily\raggedright}c
  | >{\sffamily}c |
}
\hline
\rowcolor{gray!20}\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bfseries\sffamily \texttt{id}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bfseries\sffamily \texttt{name}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries\sffamily \texttt{surname}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries\sffamily \texttt{gender}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries\sffamily \texttt{salesOrders(\dots)}} \\
\hline
001 & Abigail & Conner & F & \\
\hline
002 & Baldwin & Oliver & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
    }
    \firsthline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries date} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries deliveryDate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries products(\dots)}\\
    \hline
    100 & 30-Dic-2016 & 2-Oct-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
            }
            \firsthline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries name} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries category}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries price}\\
            \hline
            100 & 1 & Coffee & Beverage & 2.57 \cr
            \hline
            101 & 2 & Milk & Beverage & 0.80 \cr
        \end{tabular}} \cr
    \hline
    102 & 13-May-2017 & 14-May-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
            }
            \firsthline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries name} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries category}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries price}\\
            \hline
            103 & 1 & Nuggets & Chicken Meat & 4.10 \cr
            \hline
            102 & 10 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 0.99 \cr
        \end{tabular}}\cr
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
003 & Cassie & Norman & F & \\
\hline
004 & Darcy & Parker & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
    }
    \firsthline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries date} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries deliveryDate} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries products(\dots)}\\
    \hline
    101 & 5-Jan-2017 & 12-Feb-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
                | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
            }
            \firsthline
            \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries quantity} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries name} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries category}& \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries price}\\
            \hline
            103 & 1 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 2.57 \cr
        \end{tabular}} \cr
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
005 & Edmund & Spencer & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c
        | >{\ttfamily\raggedright}c |
    }
    \firsthline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries id} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries date} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries deliveryDate} &  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries products(\dots)}\\
    \hline
    103 & 13-Jun-2017 & 1-Aug-2017 &  \cr
\end{tabular} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: Depends how much styling you need, you can use a `tabular` instead of the inner `matrix`.

Comment: I know. The thing is that I would like to be able to add labels, draw arrows for Primary-Keys Foreign-Keys as presented in the former example, and so TiKz provides me a great background for drawing around my nested relational table.

Comment: the settings during the setup are pretty nontrivial hence it is really not a simple task or desirable to implement nesting in this context.

Comment: If you're referring to the bounty request, I'm no TiKz expert, so I do not know if the task is trivial or not.  As I also stated in the bounty request, “Any other method allowing to draw edges as in matrices and as in the linked example are well accepted.”

Comment: No it's nothing to do with bounty.

Comment: Since the suggestion was to keep the `matrix` for the outer environment, only using `tabular` for the inner environments, I don't see why you can't use this approach. The linked question shows arrows etc. between matrices and you could still draw those, since you'd still be in Ti*k*Z and have all the cell references of the outer `matrix` environment. If you need references to cells within the inner environments, you can use the `\subnode` macro provided by `tikzmark`, for example, to define reference points.

Comment: But the 'primary' and 'foreign key' arrows only seem to apply for the outer environment anyway, since they connect this matrix with a second one.

Comment: @cfr, I wanted to use an homogeneous approach, where I use \matrix both inside and outside... so I managed to use tables both inside and outside. So, you're saying that I could stick with the tabulars, and only add \tikzmarks in order to create links between the elements? This could be a possible solution, actually.

Comment: @jackb That's probably how I would do it unless it was part of a larger picture. In fact, it is how I usually annotate this kind of material: construct the tabulars normally and then use `tikzmark` to overlay the annotations.

Comment: If you want I could grant you the bounty if you write it as an Answer, my 50 points are already faded away, actually.

Comment: I'll write the answer if you are interested. You don't have to promise me the bounty ;). I just didn't want to spend the time on it if you didn't see it as a viable option. Somebody may come up with something better in the 4 days, so I would hold off committing your bounty until then! May not get to write it up until tonight, though. Depends how much procrastination I do.

Comment: I recognize that some users prefer to write comments when they are not sure of the answer, while others prefer to write the answer even if they do not provide a good answer, just for the sake of getting the bounty. It happened to me last time. No problem, let's see what it will happen within these 4 days.

Comment: @jackb I've posted an example based on yours using `tikzmark` so you can see how the approach works. It is a bit fiddly, but it is probably the most straightforward method I've found so far for this kind of annotation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here's an example using the approach we discussed in comments. It uses `tikzmark` to place markers in the tables and then annotates the tables using a `tikzpicture`.

I wasn't sure how the `product key` and `foreign key` notes might apply here as those link columns with the same data in different tabulars, which doesn't apply here. So I've shown how to do a couple of the other things in the linked example with `tikzmark`, and made something up which is a bit like the `product/foreign key` thing. Basically, this should give you enough to customise the approach to your needs, if you decide to do it this way.

The method requires two compilation runs. On the first run, the annotations will look a complete mess, in most cases, or will fail to show up at all, in others. This is because TeX doesn't yet know where they should go. So they just go to some arbitrary place, usually one on top of the other. On the second run, things settle down and you can see if you actually need to adjust anything and so on.

The overlaid annotations take no space, so far as TeX is concerned, so you have to make sure to allow enough room on the page. For this reason, I've changed the example to use the `article` class. [But see EDIT below for a method based on `standalone`.]

I've also tried to clean up and simplify the code for the tabulars a bit. But do note that vertical rules are widely considered evil, and horizontal rules for all rows are thought to be pursuing typographic wickedness with almost as much vigour. Coloured rows and cells are not thought much better, especially when combined with rules. (But if you have already got vertical rules, you might as well do the thing properly, I suppose. Who wants to commit typographic misdemeanours? Might just as well be hung for a sheep as a lamb ....)

Note that there is absolutely no point at all in writing `\sffamily \texttt{all of the text in the current scope}` or in saying `>{\raggedright}c`. In the first case, either you want sans or typewriter: you can't have both. In the second, either you want the text set ragged right or you want it centred: you can't have both.

The commented lines add little red tags with the names of the markers. I find this helpful when editing, if I'm starting to lose track of what is where, or if I return to edit a diagram later and want to figure out quickly what I've currently got.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape,a4paper}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,tikz}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\sffamily\arraybackslash}c}
\newenvironment{groupme}{}{}
\newcommand\headcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\firstheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\firstsubheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\subheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries #1}%
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand\markme[2][]{%
  \tikzmark{#2#1-l}#2\tikzmark{#2#1-r}%
}
\begin{document}
\hskip 0pt%
\vfill
\begin{groupme}
  \centering
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
  \ttfamily
  \noindent\tikzmark{B}\begin{tabular}{ | *{2}{c|} *{3}{s|} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!20}\firstheadcell{\markme{id}}
    & \headcell{\markme{name}}
    & \headcell{\markme{surname}}
    & \headcell{\markme{gender}}
    & \headcell{\markme{salesOrders} (\dots)} \\
    \hline
    001 & Abigail & Conner & F & \\
    \hline
    002 & Baldwin & Oliver & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{l|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      100 & 30-Dic-2016 & 2-Oct-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          100 & 1 & Coffee & Beverage & 2.57 \\
          \hline
          101 & 2 & Milk & Beverage & 0.80 \\
        \end{tabular}} \cr
      \hline
      102 & 13-May-2017 & 14-May-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          103 & 1 & Nuggets\tikzmark{n} & Chicken Meat & 4.10 \\
          \hline
          102 & 10 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 0.99 \\
        \end{tabular}}\\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    003 & Cassie & Norman & F & \\
    \hline
    004 & Darcy & Parker & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{c|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      101 & 5-Jan-2017 & 12-Feb-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          103 & 1 & SPAM\tikzmark{s} & Canned Meat & 2.57 \\
        \end{tabular}} \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    005 & Edmund & Spencer & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{c|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      103 & 13-Jun-2017 & 1-Aug-2017\tikzmark{b} &  \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}\tikzmark{E}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, font=\sffamily]
    \foreach \i in {B,E,b,s,n} {
      \coordinate (\i) at ({pic cs:\i});
%       \node [font=\tiny, red] at (\i) {\i};
    }
    \foreach \i in {name,id,salesOrders,gender,surname} {
      \foreach \j in {l,r}
      {
        \coordinate (\i-\j) at ({pic cs:\i-\j});
%         \node [font=\tiny, red] at (\i-\j) {\i-\j};
      }
    }
    \path [draw, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=10pt}] ([xshift=-2.5pt, yshift=2.5ex]id-l -| B) coordinate (tl) -- ([yshift=-1ex]b -| tl) coordinate (bl) node [midway, xshift=-10pt, rotate=90, anchor=south] {Relation};
    \draw [Latex-Latex, thick, red] ([xshift=2.5pt]n -| E) coordinate (nr) -| ([xshift=15pt]s -| nr) coordinate [pos=.75] (c) -- (s -| nr) coordinate (sr);
    \draw [thick, red] (c) -| ([xshift=10pt, yshift=-10pt]c |- bl) coordinate (c1) -| (c1 -| b) -- ++(0,-5pt) node [below, anchor=north] {Conflicting IDs!!};
    \node (a) [rounded corners, top color=blue!50!cyan!75, bottom color=blue!50!cyan, text=white, draw=blue!50!cyan, thick, above=20mm of gender-r |- tl] {Attributes};
    \draw [thick, -Latex] (a) edge (id-l |- tl) edge (name-r |- tl) edge (surname-r |- tl) edge (gender-r |- tl) -- (salesOrders-r |- tl);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{groupme}
\vfill
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

[image: annotated tabulars]

## EDIT

Here's a way to use `standalone` to create a PDF of just the annotated table. It is annoyingly fiddly, but very doable. (The annoyance is due to having to fiddle to find appropriate dimensions for the paper.)

```
\documentclass[crop=false]{standalone}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{paperwidth=230mm,paperheight=130mm,scale=1,showframe}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,tikz}
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\sffamily\arraybackslash}c}
\newenvironment{groupme}{}{}
\newcommand\headcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\firstheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\firstsubheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries #1}%
}
\newcommand\subheadcell[1]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor{gray!20}\bfseries #1}%
}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta,tikzmark,decorations.pathreplacing}
\newcommand\markme[2][]{%
  \tikzmark{#2#1-l}#2\tikzmark{#2#1-r}%
}
\standaloneenv{groupme}
\begin{document}
\hskip 0pt%
\vfill
\vfill
\centering
\begin{groupme}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}%
  \ttfamily
  \noindent\tikzmark{B}\begin{tabular}{ | *{2}{c|} *{3}{s|} }
    \hline
    \rowcolor{gray!20}\firstheadcell{\markme{id}}
    & \headcell{\markme{name}}
    & \headcell{\markme{surname}}
    & \headcell{\markme{gender}}
    & \headcell{\markme{salesOrders} (\dots)} \\
    \hline
    001 & Abigail & Conner & F & \\
    \hline
    002 & Baldwin & Oliver & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{l|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      100 & 30-Dic-2016 & 2-Oct-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          100 & 1 & Coffee & Beverage & 2.57 \\
          \hline
          101 & 2 & Milk & Beverage & 0.80 \\
        \end{tabular}} \cr
      \hline
      102 & 13-May-2017 & 14-May-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          103 & 1 & Nuggets\tikzmark{n} & Chicken Meat & 4.10 \\
          \hline
          102 & 10 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 0.99 \\
        \end{tabular}}\\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    003 & Cassie & Norman & F & \\
    \hline
    004 & Darcy & Parker & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{c|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      101 & 5-Jan-2017 & 12-Feb-2017 & {\begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{5}{c|} }
          \firsthline
          \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{quantity} & \subheadcell{name} & \subheadcell{category} & \subheadcell{price}\\
          \hline
          103 & 1 & SPAM\tikzmark{s} & Canned Meat & 2.57 \\
        \end{tabular}} \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
    005 & Edmund & Spencer & M &  \begin{tabular}[t]{ | *{4}{c|} }
      \firsthline
      \firstsubheadcell{id} & \subheadcell{date} & \subheadcell{deliveryDate} & \subheadcell{products (\dots)}\\
      \hline
      103 & 13-Jun-2017 & 1-Aug-2017\tikzmark{b} &  \\
    \end{tabular} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}\tikzmark{E}%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture, font=\sffamily]
    \foreach \i in {B,E,b,s,n} {
      \coordinate (\i) at ({pic cs:\i});
%       \node [font=\tiny, red] at (\i) {\i};
    }
    \foreach \i in {name,id,salesOrders,gender,surname} {
      \foreach \j in {l,r}
      {
        \coordinate (\i-\j) at ({pic cs:\i-\j});
%         \node [font=\tiny, red] at (\i-\j) {\i-\j};
      }
    }
    \path [draw, thick, decorate, decoration={brace, mirror, amplitude=10pt}] ([xshift=-2.5pt, yshift=2.5ex]id-l -| B) coordinate (tl) -- ([yshift=-1ex]b -| tl) coordinate (bl) node [midway, xshift=-10pt, rotate=90, anchor=south] {Relation};
    \draw [Latex-Latex, thick, red] ([xshift=2.5pt]n -| E) coordinate (nr) -| ([xshift=15pt]s -| nr) coordinate [pos=.75] (c) -- (s -| nr) coordinate (sr);
    \draw [thick, red] (c) -| ([xshift=10pt, yshift=-10pt]c |- bl) coordinate (c1) -| (c1 -| b) -- ++(0,-5pt) node [below, anchor=north] {Conflicting IDs!!};
    \node (a) [rounded corners, top color=blue!50!cyan!75, bottom color=blue!50!cyan, text=white, draw=blue!50!cyan, thick, above=20mm of gender-r |- tl] {Attributes};
    \draw [thick, -Latex] (a) edge (id-l |- tl) edge (name-r |- tl) edge (surname-r |- tl) edge (gender-r |- tl) -- (salesOrders-r |- tl);
  \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{groupme}
\vfill
\clearpage
\end{document}
```

Output as above.

Comment: So, if I want to use it as a source for an external picture, I must use the standalone package. But now, \vfill is not recognized anymore. What shall I do in this case?

Comment: How are you externalising exactly? You cannot use Ti*k*Z's `external` library to externalise this, for example. But you could compile it with `standalone`. You just have to figure out the page size you need. Annoying, but doable.

Comment: No, I'm saying that I want to generate a PDF with standalone. But I had an error with vfill at compile time that didn't appear with article.

Comment: @jackb Please see edit above.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about that, thanks a lot!

Comment: @jackb Note that the commented lines in the code add red markers with the names of the coordinates. I often find this helpful when editing, as I lose track of what is where at times.

Answer (score 6):

You can't nest `tikz` matrices but you can overlap them.

The matrices are nodes and can be positioned w.r.t. a cell (which is a node, too) of another `tikz matrix`.

If you need to refer to a node-cell, you have to create it, even if it's empty (see the comment in my code).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta}
\colorlet{mygray}{gray!20}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=latex,
    main matrix/.style={%
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={align=left, inner ysep=4pt, inner xsep=4pt, anchor=west}, 
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\strut\ttfamily,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mygray,font=\strut\bfseries}},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width{"idiii"}}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={text width=width{"namexxxxx"}}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=width{"surnamexx"}}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={text width=width{"genderx"}}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={text width=44em}},
    },
    sub matrix/.style args={#1/#2}{%
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={align=left, inner ysep=#1, inner xsep=4pt},% anchor=west}, 
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\strut\ttfamily,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mygray,font=\strut\bfseries}},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width{"idiii"}}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={text width=width{"datexxxxxxxi"}}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=width{"deliveryDatexx"}}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={text width=#2}},
    },
    subsub matrix/.style args={#1/#2}{%
        matrix of nodes,
        nodes in empty cells,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={align=center,inner ysep=#1, inner xsep=4pt}, 
        inner sep=0pt,
        font=\strut\ttfamily,
        row 1/.style={nodes={fill=mygray,font=\strut\bfseries}},
        column 1/.style={nodes={text width=width{"idiii"}}},
        column 2/.style={nodes={text width=width{"quantityxx"}}},
        column 3/.style={nodes={text width=width{"namexxx"}}},
        column 4/.style={nodes={text width=#2}},
        column 5/.style={nodes={text width=width{"XX.XX"}}},
    },
    ]   
    \path[use as bounding box] (-14,-9) rectangle (13,6);
    % main table
    \matrix[main matrix] (main) {%
        id & name & surname & gender & salesOrders(\dots) \\
        001 & Abigail & Conner & F & \\
        002 & Baldwin & Oliver & M & \\
        \\
        \\
        \\
        \\
        \\
        &&&&\\% you have to create the nodes (even if empty) if you need to refer to them
        003 & Cassie & Norman & F & \\
        004 & Darcy & Parker & M &  \\
        \\
        &&&&\\
        005 & Edmund & Spencer & M & \\
        &&&&\\
    };
    % main table rules
    \draw (main-1-1.north west) -- (main-15-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,5} {%
        \draw (main-1-\icol.north east) -- (main-15-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (main-1-1.north west) -- (main-1-5.north east);
    \foreach \irow in {1,2,9,10,13,15} {%
        \draw (main-\irow-1.south west) -- (main-\irow-5.south east);
    }
    % first sub table
    \matrix[sub matrix={3.8pt/26em}, below=2pt of main-2-5] (sub1) {%
        id & date& deliveryDate &products(\dots) \\
        100 & 30-Dic-2016 & 2-Oct-2017 & \\
        \\
        &&&\\
        102 & 13-May-2017 & 14-May-2017 &\\
        \\
        &&&\\
    };  
    \draw (sub1-1-1.north west) -- (sub1-7-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,4} {%
        \draw (sub1-1-\icol.north east) -- (sub1-7-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (sub1-1-1.north west) -- (sub1-1-4.north east);
    \foreach \irow in {1,4} {%
        \draw (sub1-\irow-1.south west) -- (sub1-\irow-4.south east);
    }
    % second sub table
    \matrix[sub matrix={3.5pt/25em}, below=2pt of main-10-5] (sub2) {%
        id & date& deliveryDate &products(\dots) \\
        101 & 5-Jan-2017 & 12-Feb-2017 & \\
        &&&\\
    };  
    \draw (sub2-1-1.north west) -- (sub2-3-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,4} {%
        \draw (sub2-1-\icol.north east) -- (sub2-3-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (sub2-1-1.north west) -- (sub2-1-4.north east);
    \draw (sub2-1-1.south west) -- (sub2-1-4.south east);
    % third sub table
    \matrix[sub matrix={3.4pt/width{"productsxxxxxx"}}, below=2pt of main-13-5] (sub3) {%
        id & date& deliveryDate &products(\dots) \\
        103 & 13-Jun-2017 & 1-Aug-2017 &  \\
    };  
    \draw (sub3-1-1.north west) -- (sub3-2-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,4} {%
        \draw (sub3-1-\icol.north east) -- (sub3-2-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (sub3-1-1.north west) -- (sub3-1-4.north east);
    \draw (sub3-1-1.south west) -- (sub3-1-4.south east);
    % first sub sub table
    \matrix[subsub matrix={3.4pt/5.5em}, below=2pt of sub1-1-4] (subsub1) {%
        id & quantity &  name &  category &  price\\
        100 & 1 & Coffee & Beverage & 2.57 \\
        101 & 2 & Milk & Beverage & 0.80 \\
    };  
    \draw (subsub1-1-1.north west) -- (subsub1-3-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,5} {%
        \draw (subsub1-1-\icol.north east) -- (subsub1-3-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (subsub1-1-1.north west) -- (subsub1-1-5.north east);
    \draw (subsub1-1-1.south west) -- (subsub1-1-5.south east);
    % second sub sub table
    \matrix[subsub matrix={3.4pt/7em}, below=2pt of sub1-4-4] (subsub2) {%
        id & quantity &  name &  category &  price\\
        103 & 1 & Nuggets & Chicken Meat & 4.10 \\
        102 & 10 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 0.99  \\
    };  
    \draw (subsub2-1-1.north west) -- (subsub2-3-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,5} {%
        \draw (subsub2-1-\icol.north east) -- (subsub2-3-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (subsub2-1-1.north west) -- (subsub2-1-5.north east);
    \draw (subsub2-1-1.south west) -- (subsub2-1-5.south east);
    % third sub sub table
    \matrix[subsub matrix={2.8pt/6.5em}, below=2pt of sub2-1-4] (subsub3) {%
        id & quantity &  name &  category &  price\\
        103 & 1 & SPAM & Canned Meat & 2.57\\
    };  
    \draw (subsub3-1-1.north west) -- (subsub3-2-1.south west);
    \foreach \icol in {1,2,...,5} {%
        \draw (subsub3-1-\icol.north east) -- (subsub3-2-\icol.south east);
    }
    \draw (subsub3-1-1.north west) -- (subsub3-1-5.north east);
    \draw (subsub3-1-1.south west) -- (subsub3-1-5.south east);
    % just for example
    \node[draw] at (4,-7) (examplenode) {just to show some arrows};
    \draw[->] (examplenode.west) to[out=180, in=180] (main-3-1.west);
    \draw[->] (examplenode.north) to[out=90, in=180] (sub1-2-1.west);
    \draw[->] (examplenode.south) to[out=-90, in=180] (sub3-2-1.west);
    \draw[->] (examplenode.east) to[out=0, in=180] (subsub1-3-1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: See the edited question, where I provided some example of the desired effect without TiKz.

Comment: thanks a lot for your effort, it is even a very long code, but it seems to me that this solution is very hard to maintain: when I want to change the table structure, I have to re-write both the inner tables and the outer ones.

Comment: @jackb I think a simple `tikz`-only solution needs some little manual adjustments. A solution with `tikzmark`, like cfr's one, is better, waiting to be able to nest `tikz` matrices.