# LaTeX Flowchart: Connect from diamond to far off rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I am trying to connect from the first diamond to the first rectangle of the second column.

My code is below.

Please help me to fix this problem.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
\tikzstyle{line}=[draw] % here
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}


\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{flushend}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}

\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
\usepackage{array}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{lmm}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cll}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
%\makeatletter

\begin{document}

\colorlet{lcfree}{black} 
\colorlet{lcnorm}{black}
\colorlet{lccong}{black}

\providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{\relax}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
>=triangle 60,              % Nice arrows; your taste may be different
start chain=going below,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
node distance=10mm and 75mm, % Global setup of box spacing
every join/.style={norm},   % Default linetype for connecting boxes
]


% ------------------------------------------------- 
% A few box styles 
% <on chain> *and* <on grid> reduce the need for manual relative
% positioning of nodes
\tikzset{
 base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
 proc/.style={base, rectangle, text width=12em},
 test/.style={base, diamond, aspect=2, text width=8em},
 term/.style={proc, rounded corners},
 % coord node style is used for placing corners of connecting lines
 coord/.style={coordinate, on chain, on grid, node distance=2mm and 12mm},
 % nmark node style is used for coordinate debugging marks
 nmark/.style={draw, cyan, circle, font={\sffamily\bfseries}},
 % -------------------------------------------------
 % Connector line styles for different parts of the diagram
 norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
 free/.style={->, draw, lcfree},
 cong/.style={->, draw, lccong},
 it/.style={font={\small\itshape}}
}
% -------------------------------------------------
% Use join to connect a node to the previous one 
\node [term, join]  (p0)    {t  =  0\\ Intialize $m_i$, $q_i$, $p_i$,\\ and $q_k$, $p_k$, $a_k$.};
\node [proc, join] (p1) {Sense AoI and update inforamtion maps.};
\node [proc, join]      {Detect targets and update inforamtion lists.};
\node [test, join] (t1) {Is $N_i={\emptyset}$?};
\node [proc] (p2) {Evaluate the fitness of each target as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-A.};
\node [proc, join] (p3) {Dertermin the next operating mode as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-B.};
\node [test, join] (t2) {Track a target $k$?};
\node [proc, join=by free]  (p7) {Calculate $f_i^t$ as in Eq. (12).};
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\node [proc,  right=of p1] (p4) {Exchange inforamtion maps with all neighbours.};
\node [proc, join=by free]   {Transimit information lists to all neighbours.};
\node [test, join] (t3) {other nodes?};
\node [proc, join=by free, right=of p2] (p5) {Transimit information lists to these nodes.};
\node [proc,  right=of t2] (p6) {Calculate $q_{i_s}$ as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-C.};
\node [proc, join=by free, right=of p7]  (p8) {Calculate $f_i^s$ as in Eq. (13).};
% Some more nodes specifically positioned (we could have avoided this,
% but try it and you'll see the result is ugly).
% -------------------------------------------------
% Now we place the coordinate nodes for the connectors with angles, or
% with annotations. We also mark them for debugging.
\node [coord, right=of t1] (c7)  {}; \cmark{7}  



% -------------------------------------------------
% A couple of boxes have annotations
% -------------------------------------------------
% All the other connections come out of tests and need annotating
% First, the straight north-south connections. In each case, we first
% draw a path with a (consistently positioned) annotation node, then
% we draw the arrow itself.
\path (t1.south) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$y$} (p2);
\draw [->,lcnorm] (t1.south) -- (p2);
\path (t1.east) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$n$} (p4);
\draw [->,lcnorm] (t1.east) -- (p4.west);
\path (t3.south) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$y$} (p5);
\draw [->,lcnorm] (t3.south) -- (p5);
\path (p5.west) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {} (p2); 
\draw [->,lcnorm] (p5.west) -- (p2);
\path (t2.east) -| node [very near start, yshift=1em] {$n$} (c7); 
\draw [->,lcfree] (t2.east) -- (p6.west);

    % -------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While you wait for an answer to this question, can you go back to your previous ones and look if the answers solve your problems and accept them, if they do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[12pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,openright]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
    \tikzstyle{line}=[draw] % here
    %%%<
    \usepackage{verbatim}


    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{enumerate}
    \usepackage{flushend}
    \usepackage{graphics,graphicx}
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains}
    %%%<
    \usepackage{verbatim}

    \DeclareMathOperator*{\argmax}{arg\,max}
    \usepackage{array}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{lmm}{Lemma}
    \newtheorem{cll}{Corollary}
    \newtheorem{dfn}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
    %\makeatletter

    \begin{document}

    \colorlet{lcfree}{black} 
    \colorlet{lcnorm}{black}
    \colorlet{lccong}{black}

    \providecommand{\cmark}[2][]{\relax}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[%
    >=triangle 60,              % Nice arrows; your taste may be different
    start chain=going below,    % General flow is top-to-bottom
    node distance=10mm and 75mm, % Global setup of box spacing
    every join/.style={norm},   % Default linetype for connecting boxes
    ]


    % ------------------------------------------------- 
    % A few box styles 
    % <on chain> *and* <on grid> reduce the need for manual relative
    % positioning of nodes
    \tikzset{
     base/.style={draw, on chain, on grid, align=center, minimum height=4ex},
     proc/.style={base, rectangle, text width=12em},
     test/.style={base, diamond, aspect=2, text width=8em},
     term/.style={proc, rounded corners},
     % coord node style is used for placing corners of connecting lines
     coord/.style={coordinate, on chain, on grid, node distance=2mm and 12mm},
     % nmark node style is used for coordinate debugging marks
     nmark/.style={draw, cyan, circle, font={\sffamily\bfseries}},
     % -------------------------------------------------
     % Connector line styles for different parts of the diagram
     norm/.style={->, draw, lcnorm},
     free/.style={->, draw, lcfree},
     cong/.style={->, draw, lccong},
     it/.style={font={\small\itshape}}
    }
    % -------------------------------------------------
    % Use join to connect a node to the previous one 
    \node [term, join]  (p0)    {t  =  0\\ Intialize $m_i$, $q_i$, $p_i$,\\ and $q_k$, $p_k$, $a_k$.};
    \node [proc, join] (p1) {Sense AoI and update inforamtion maps.};
    \node [proc, join]      {Detect targets and update inforamtion lists.};
    \node [test, join] (t1) {Is $N_i={\emptyset}$?};
    \node [proc] (p2) {Evaluate the fitness of each target as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-A.};
    \node [proc, join] (p3) {Dertermin the next operating mode as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-B.};
    \node [test, join] (t2) {Track a target $k$?};
    \node [proc, join=by free]  (p7) {Calculate $f_i^t$ as in Eq. (12).};
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    \node [proc,  right=of p1] (p4) {Exchange inforamtion maps with all neighbours.};
    \node [proc, join=by free]   {Transimit information lists to all neighbours.};
    \node [test, join] (t3) {other nodes?};
    \node [proc, join=by free, right=of p2] (p5) {Transimit information lists to these nodes.};
    \node [proc,  right=of t2] (p6) {Calculate $q_{i_s}$ as in Section \ref{sec:Proposed distributed semi-flocking}-C.};
    \node [proc, join=by free, right=of p7]  (p8) {Calculate $f_i^s$ as in Eq. (13).};
    % Some more nodes specifically positioned (we could have avoided this,
    % but try it and you'll see the result is ugly).
    % -------------------------------------------------
    % Now we place the coordinate nodes for the connectors with angles, or
    % with annotations. We also mark them for debugging.
    \node [coord, right=of t1] (c7)  {}; \cmark{7}  



    % -------------------------------------------------
    % A couple of boxes have annotations
    % -------------------------------------------------
    % All the other connections come out of tests and need annotating
    % First, the straight north-south connections. In each case, we first
    % draw a path with a (consistently positioned) annotation node, then
    % we draw the arrow itself.
    \path (t1.south) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$y$} (p2);
\draw [->,lcnorm] (t1.south) -- (p2);
%\path (t1.east) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$n$} (p4);
%\draw [->,lcnorm] (t1.east) -- (p4.west);
\draw[->,lcnorm] (t1.east)--++(0:10mm) node[near start, above] {$n$} |-(p4);
\path (t3.south) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {$y$} (p5);
\draw [->,lcnorm] (t3.south) -- (p5);
\path (p5.west) to node [near start, xshift=1em] {} (p2); 
\draw [->,lcnorm] (p5.west) -- (p2);
\path (t2.east) -| node [very near start, yshift=1em] {$n$} (c7); 
\draw [->,lcfree] (t2.east) -- (p6.west);

    % -------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------------------------------
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I've always thought there is missing syntax to tikz, expanding the `-|` and `|-` operations to enable just writing `-|-`or `|-|` with optional position parameters for such use cases.

Comment: @marsupilam You can use Qrrbrbirlbel's `-orth` library which defines this syntax. See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137581/1952

Comment: @Ignasi Thanks ! Did not know that ! Will look into it.

Comment: @nandeeshv If the posted answer satisfies your request, you may want to upvote it, and accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: @marsupilam Thanks for reminding. I did it.